# Si no recibo datos de AJAX con DataTable, ¿cómo puedo ofrecer otra salida?

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

Tengo el siguiente código

```
let listData = function() {
    dataTableData = $('#dataTableData').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        ajax: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'actions/listData.php'
        },
        columns: [{
                data: 'id'
            },
            {
                data: 'name'
            },
            {
                data: 'country'
            },
            {
                data: 'account'
            }]
    });
}

listData();
```

Cuando tengo datos todo funciona correctamente, el caso es que a veces dicha tabla se queda sin registros en la base de datos, entonces, al hacer la llamada AJAX no devuelve ninguna información y sale el siguiente error en Chrome al intentar visualizar la tabla:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

El caso es que no se cómo comprobar que el método AJAX devuelve datos, y en caso de que devuelva FALSE, no se cargue la tabla y no se muestre este error o se ofrezca otra salida que avise al usuario que no existen registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar primero a obtener los datos y tratarlos, así te evitas la excepción.

```
dataTableData = $('#dataTableData').DataTable({

    "ajax": {
        url: 'actions/listData.php' 
        dataSrc: function (data) {
            let res = "";
            if(data == false || data == null)                    
                return JSON.parse(res);
            else
                return JSON.parse(data);
        }
    },
    "columns": [{
                data: 'id'
            },
            {
                data: 'name'
            },
            {
                data: 'country'
            },
            {
                data: 'account'
            }]  
});
```

con `dataSrc` manejas la respuesta evitando la excepción.

Después de los comentarios, puedes realizar primero el ajax y despues, en caso de que tenga datos pintar la tabla:

```
let tuArray = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "actions/listData.php"
                });
if(tuArray != false || tuArray != null)
    //Cargar datatable
```

O también puedes cambiar tu función para que te retorne un array vacío y así no sale la excepción y no tienes que añadir más código.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres. En caso de que AJAX devuelva false o null, seguiría dando error, puesto que dataSrc usa el valor retornado para cargar la tabla.

Comment: si te devuelve false o null, eso será data, ahi puedes crearte un json vacio para que no crashee, edito con tu problema

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien, en listData.php se devuelve un array si hay datos y false o null si no encuentra datos. Entonces está solución es lo mismo que tengo programado. Lo que busco, es que si es false o null no cargue la tabla, dado que si data es algunas de esas opciones o "", columns intentará cargar esa información y se producirá el error. No sé si entiende mejor ahora.

Comment: Haciendo una llamada ajax antes de cargar la tabla y en caso de que tenga datos pintar la tabla, en vez de hacerlo dentro, o si lo prefieres también puedes cambiar en el php para recibir un array vacia en vez de null o false. Edito de nuevo con la nueva info